# Why a body can't have net charge in fraction of a Coulomb?

Tags: electrostatics, charge, discrete

Q. Quantisation of charge implies:-

(a) charge cannot be destroyed 
(b) charge exists on particles 
(c) there is a minimum permissible charge on a particle 
(d) charge, which is a fraction of a coulomb is not possible.

**On answer key it's shown that the correct answer is (d)** 
but as far as i know quantization of charge **never** describe that "net charge on a body must be integral multiple of C" instead it's **e** i.e. elementary charge which is far smaller than Coulomb so on that basis how can we tell it will never show a charge of fraction of a coulomb ? 

what am i missing here ? please help and thanks in advance .

Comment: At a glance, it looks like a bad question. There's plenty of that in high school physics material.

Comment: i don't know sir , i was just solving mcqs from online sites and this question really questioned my entire study , please tell me sir whether the question is wrong or i am doing something wrong here , here's the website [link](https://physicsgurukul.com/2020/01/28/class-12-physics-ch-01-electric-charges-fields-mcq/) question no. is 9 | thanks please help or i can't sleep :(

Comment: You already know the answer. Look here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oil_drop_experiment. Millikan and Fletcher didn’t put a mole (or several) of electrons on their oil drops! ;-)

Comment: (d) is incorrect because (as you point out) 1 Coulomb is actually a huge number of elementary charges.  Charge comes in discrete multiples of $e=1.6\times 10^{-19}$Coulombs so that even a charge of some micro-Coulombs is a huge number of elementary charges.  Note that quarks are known to carry $1/3$ of the basic unit of charge.

Comment: Where does it say that the correct answer is (d)?

Comment: @nasu on the ans key :)

Comment: @ZeroTheHero
Thanks a million sir that's exactly what i wanted to hear ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A body can indeed have a charge equal to a fraction of a coulomb. But any material object cannot have a charge which would work out to be a fraction of that on an *electron*.

Comment: Also, or a fraction of that on a proton. Right?

Comment: @BobD, yes yes. -NN

Comment: thanks for your help & seriously does everyone question and comments gets down voted and flagged here for no reason :(

Comment: @EternalOdball, some of the professionals here have little patience for questions they consider ill-posed or trivial, and they don't hesitate to convey their feelings- sometimes in blunt or unkind language. I too can be harsh at times but I try to keep it in check and not assume the worst of someone who's sticking out their neck to ask a question here. Please don't let it get at you. -NN

Comment: @EternalOdball people react negatively to  “poorly researched”, “solve-it-for-me” or such questions where the poster has clearly not done any serious effort to think about the question.  Your question is somewhat borderline as you could have looked up sources challenging your answer key, and include the difference in answers in your question, but you are a new contributor so it’s not that big of a deal for this time.  Kindly be aware this is not an instant answering service.

Comment: @EternalOdball to add to my previous comment see https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/36194

Comment: @ZeroTheHero yeah i understand it was my fault for using tags incorrectly the problem was that in my book this topic is not in "electrostatics" instead it's on "Electric Charges" which is a different chapter while my question was corrected as i hadn't used the tag "electrostatics" which i really apologize for . Thanks for giving time ...

Comment: @EternalOdball not sure it's really about the tagging.  Just be sure to construct your questions so they address conceptual rather than exercise-specific issues, and make it clear that you did some work on your own (through various sources, including this site).  Writing a question is difficult and yes the site has a high bar, which is why it's so useful.